# Xcode 9 enable Server fails because "xcsd" keychain password

Tags: xcode, xcode9, osx-server, xcode-server

I currently try to setup an Xcode Server with Xcode 9 but I stuck with this Keychain Password request. 
I guess it has something to do with the previous Xcode/OS X Server Installation as there Xcode Server was part of OS X Server.

But how do I get rid of this?

EDIT: As it came up in the comments: 
Neither the password of a the system/admin-user nor the one of the dedicated account for the Xcode Server is accepted.

[image: Keychain password request for xcsd]

Comment: enter your system password and click on always allow

Comment: Nope, this does not work … also the password for the dedicated user created for Xcode Server does not work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Only working solution for me:

- Backup the folder /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/
- Remove it
- Activate Xcode Server

Keep in mind that the new Xcode server doesn't have hosted repositories anymore, so if used them, they are in the HostedRepositories folder. You have to move them to a different service (eg. github).

Comment: Yes I did it like that … I will have to setup repositories again, but that's not that big of a problem.

Comment: @MatzeLoCal, you cannot setup repositories again (I mean local repositories) because they are no longer available on Xcode server. You can only use GitHub

Comment: @AndrzejMartyna of course I can. The only thing I can't do is to set it up via macOS Server but setting it up manually is no problem and that's what I did. Everything is working fine again here

Answer (score 7):

I tried all of the above... however the only thing that worked for me was resetting the entire server with this command.  Open terminal and try:

```
sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcscontrol --reset
```

This command saved me from giving up!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and after a few hours of try and error. I think I kind of got the solution... 
I went to keychain access, and selected the xcsd keychain, then went to menu - edit - delete keychain 'xcsd', then after restart the issue of asking for that mystery password was fixed.

Comment: Make it worse... now a weird alert appears.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted "xcsd.crt", "xcsd.key", "xcsnginx.crt", "xcsnginx.key" and "xcsnginx.pass" from:
/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Certificates

and "xcsd.keychain" and "xcsnginx.keychain" from:
/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Keychains

And then was able to start the Xcode server.
(It might very well be the case, that the xcsd.xxx files would have been enough, but I can not try it out now that the error is gone)